# Using equalTo() function in Firebase Database JavaScript v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use the equalTo function in the Firebase Database JavaScript v9 SDK. It's not very well documented like V8 is so can't figure out how to do what I want to do.

I want to filter results by the `type` field. My parent field is `request-log` with child elements like below.

```
{"backtrace":false,"message":false,"organisationID":"Empty","postData":false,"referrer":"Empty","remoteIP":"0.0.0.0","requestMethod":"POST","time":1630129562,"type":"Error","url":"Empty","user":{"email":"Empty","firstName":"George","id":37,"lastName":"Bates"},"userAgent":"Empty"}
```

I am trying the following, but not getting any results when loaded:

```
const readNewLogEntries = query(child(ref(db), 'request-log'), equalTo('Error', 'type'));
```

I have also tried this, as the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#equalto) say for the 2nd argument in the `equalTo()` function

> This argument is only allowed if ordering by child, value, or priority.

But this isn't working either

```
const readNewLogEntries = query(child(ref(db), 'request-log'), orderByChild('type'), equalTo('Request', 'type'));
```

EDIT: Screenshot of DB

[image: Screenshot of DB]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of database structure?

Comment: Just added now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second parameter from `equalTo()`.

> The optional key argument can be used to further limit the range of the query. If it is specified, then children that have exactly the specified value must also have exactly the specified key as their key name. This can be used to filter result sets with many matches for the same value.

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const readNewLogEntries = await get(
    query(ref(db, "request-log"), orderByChild("type"), equalTo("Request"))
    // Filters where "type" is equal to "Request". Single arg here ⬆ 
  );
  console.log(readNewLogEntries.val())
  return readNewLogEntries.val();
};
```

You can read more about the parameters in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Query#equalto)